# how to create a list of words using seq in bash

Tags: bash, sequence, seq

I am using **seq -s " " -f " data%g :" 5** to create

```
data1 : data2 : data3 : data4 : data 5 :
```

However, I want it to start a number of my choice instead of 1 and not to have ":" symbol at the very end. For example something like this:

```
data3 : data4 : data5
```

Is there any one-line solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Current output:

```
seq -s " " -f " data%g :" 5
data1 : data2 : data3 : data4 : data 5 :
```

Desired:

```
data3 : data4 : data5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
start=3; seq -s" : " -f "data%g" $start 5
```

The output:

```
data3 : data4 : data5
```

---

`start=3` - custom variable that contains starting index

`-s" : "` - item separator

`$start 5` - represents the range of the sequence. In our case: from `3` to `5`

Answer (score 1):

alternative on `bash`

```
echo data{3..5} | sed 's/ / : /g'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it without using an external program :

```
set -- {3..5} ; (($#>1)) && printf "%s:" "${@:1:$#-1 }" ; printf "%s\n" "${@: -1}"
```

Please note that this will overwrite positional parameters.